# Java: have integer, need it in byte in 0x00 format

Tags: java

I have an integer used to seed my for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < value; i++)
```

Within my for loop I am seeding a byte array with byte content values that increment +1. For instance `new byte[]{0x00};` But the `0x00` needs to be `0x01` on the next iteration, how can I convert my value of integer `i` into a value of byte in the 0x00 format?

I tried things like `Byte.valueOf(Integer.toHexString(i))` but this just gives me a value that looks like `0` instead of `0x00`.

Comment: There is no such thing as "a byte in XY format". A byte is simply the smallest addressable unit in your memory, and usually has 8 bits. That's all we know about bytes.

Comment: "0x42" is a formatted *hexadecimal text representation* of the value 66 (which is itself a *decimal text representation* in this comment ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
new byte[]{0x00}
```

is actually equivalent to

```
new byte[]{0}
```

The 0x00 notation is just an alternative way to write integer constants, and if the integer constant is in the range -128 to 127, then it can be used as a byte.

If you have an existing integer variable that you want to use, and its value is in the range -128 to 127, then you just have to cast it:

```
int i = 1;
new byte[]{(byte)i};
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the real problem is that you are confused about number representations and text renderings of numbers.  Here are some key facts that you need to understand:

- The `byte` type is the set of integral values from -128 to +127.
- All integral types use the same representation (2's complement).  The difference between the different types is their ranges.
- When you "see" a number, what you are seeing is a rendering of the number into a sequence of characters.  There are MANY possible renderings; e.g. the number represented in memory as `00101010` (42) can be rendered as `"42"` or `"+42"` or `"0x2a"` or ... `"forty two"`.
- The default format for rendering a `byte`, `short`, `int` and `long` is the same; i.e. an optional minus sign followed by 1 or more decimal digits (with no zero padding).  If you want to see your numbers formatted differently, then you need to do the formatting explicitly; e.g. using `String.format(...)`.

So to pull this together, if you want the bytes to look like `0x00` and `0x01` when you output or display them, you need to format them appropriately as you output / display them.  In your example code, I doubt that there is anything wrong with the numbers themselves, or with the loop you are using to populate the array.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the **string representation** of the value with the value itself. A value can be represented as binary, decimal, or hex, but it is still the same value.

If you want to use your integer to initialise a byte array, you just need to cast your integer value to a byte value as follows:

```
arr[i] = (byte) i;
```

Comment: Yep. `new byte[]{0x00};` is identical to `new byte[]{0};`

Comment: thanks! yeah it wasn't about printing it sorry if that part of the question was misleading, it was about constructing the byte array. The device I was sending byte commands too was erroring, so I got confused about my formats

Comment: @RD: "You are confusing the string representation of the value with the value itself." - absolutely correct.  And I thought you were asking about the "string representation", not about the "value".  I hope you also now understand how a "byte" differs from an "int" or a short, when they're inter-convertible ... and when they're not.

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
new byte[]{(byte)i}
```

How you print this array is another matter. Look up printf in the API reference.

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to note that 0 is NOT the same thing as 0x00. If i were to use:

```
ColorChooserOutputText.append(Integer.toHexString(list[i].getRed()));                                           
ColorChooserOutputText.append(Integer.toHexString(list[i].getGreen()));                                      
ColorChooserOutputText.append(Integer.toHexString(list[i].getBlue()));
```

and wanted to return the color, Purple it would return: ff0cc Which would be fine if I were just using Java. But if you are going between Java and something that had format specific needs ff0cc would not produce purple.. ff00cc is actually purple.

```
    //Declare some variables.
    Color HexColor = JButton1.getBackground();

    String MyRValue = null;
    String MyGValue = null;
    String MyBValue = null;

    //Get Hex Value
    MyRValue = Integer.toHexString(HexColor.getRed());
    MyGValue = Integer.toHexString(HexColor.getGreen());
    MyBValue = Integer.toHexString(HexColor.getBlue());

    //Make sure to keep both 0's                    
    MyRValue = ("00"+MyRValue).substring(MyRValue.length());
    MyGValue = ("00"+MyGValue).substring(MyGValue.length());
    MyBValue = ("00"+MyBValue).substring(MyBValue.length());

    //Format your HexColor to #00ff00, #000000, #ff00ee
    JTextArea1.append("#");
    JTextArea1.append(MyRValue+MyGValue+MyBValue);
    JTextArea1.append(", ");
```

Answer (score -1):

String.Format ("%02x") is your friend :)

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/1195/

Comment: Unfortunately, he will find that there is no way to put the result of that in a byte array ......